# emacs: How to Capture stdout from dired-do-shell-command?

Tags: emacs, dired

In Emacs, is there a way to capture the stdout of dired-do-shell-command, say to the kill-ring?

Without knowing how, I end up going to the *Messages* buffer and getting the stdout manually from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Help for that command says that output goes to a buffer named `*Shell Command Output*`, assuming command has not `&`.  If this is the case, this piece of code will do what you want:

```
(defun do-shell-and-copy-to-kill-ring (command &optional arg file-list)
  (interactive
   (let ((files (dired-get-marked-files t current-prefix-arg)))
     (list
      (dired-read-shell-command "! on %s: " current-prefix-arg files)
      current-prefix-arg
      files)))
  (dired-do-shell-command command arg file-list)
  (with-current-buffer "*Shell Command Output*"
    (copy-region-as-kill (point-min) (point-max))))
```

For async commands, you need to wait for them and look in `*Async Shell Command*` buffer.

Comment: Thanks! I used this to wire your solution into my setup: (defun my-dired-mode-keys ()
  "Modify keymaps used by `dired-mode'."
  (local-set-key (kbd "C-c d") 'do-shell-and-copy-to-kill-ring))

(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'my-dired-mode-keys)